# Replace in inner HTML, excluding some elements

Tags: jquery, regex

How I could change `foo` to `bar` in `#wrapper` element, but don't change it inside `pre > code`?

I tried the code shown below, but it doesn't work properly: it changes all `foo`s, no matter where they are located.

```js
$('#wrapper').children().not('pre > code').each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html()
        .replace(/foo/g, 'bar'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>foo</p>

    <pre style="white-space: pre-line;">
        <code>
            foo
            foo
            foo
        </code>
    </pre>

    <p>foo</p>
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>foo</p>

    <pre style="white-space: pre-line;">
        <code>
            foo
            foo
            foo
        </code>
    </pre>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `.not('pre > code')` excludes `<code>` elements but it does not exclude `<pre>` elements. The easiest fix is to exclude both `pre` and `pre > code`. Rather than use `children().not(...)` it's simpler to just use a single selector:

```js
$('#wrapper :not(pre):not(pre > code)').each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html()
        .replace(/foo/g, 'bar'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>foo</p>

    <pre style="white-space: pre-line;">
        <code>
            foo
            foo
            foo
        </code>
    </pre>

    <p>foo</p>
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>foo</p>

    <pre style="white-space: pre-line;">
        <code>
            foo
            foo
            foo
        </code>
    </pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you could just check if the element is a pre.

```js
$('#wrapper').children().each(function() {
    if (!$(this).is('pre'))
      $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/foo/g, 'bar'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>foo</p>

    <pre style="white-space: pre-line;">
        <code>
            foo
            foo
            foo
        </code>
    </pre>

    <p>foo</p>
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>foo</p>

    <pre style="white-space: pre-line;">
        <code>
            foo
            foo
            foo
        </code>
    </pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just a selector issue.

Change the first line of your JavaScript to:

`$('#wrapper').children(':not(pre)').each(function() {`